# Explicit Interface And Generic / Dynamic Type Conversion

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, explicit-interface

Before I state my issue let me give some background information on what I'm trying to do, because perhaps there's a better way to achieve it.

I got a class `C` which inherits two interfaces `A` and `B`.

```
public interface A
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public interface B
{
    void DoStuff();
}
```

C implements two different bodies for `DoStuff`.

```
void A.DoStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");
}

void B.DoStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine("B");
}
```

I know of course `DoStuff` can be called like below.

```
var c = new C();
var a = (A)c;
a.DoStuff();
var b = (B)c;
b.DoStuff();
```

What I want to do though is to avoid converting `C` to either `A` or `B` and then calling `DoStuff` on `A` or `B`.

So what I though was that I could implement a generic method to do this for me and so I first tried like this.

```
public void DoStuff<T>()
{
    var i = (T)this;
    i.DoStuff();
}
```

Of course that won't work considering you can convert `this` to `T` and it causes a compiler error, so my next step was to try to create a static method that passed the instance of `this` and then did the conversion in there.

```
private static To ConvertToDoStuffInterface<From, To>(From from)
{
    return (To)from;
}
```

I did not expect that to work, but it was worth a try. As I expected it would cause a compiler error, because `From` cannot explicitly convert to `To`.

My last resort was using the `dynamic` keyword and of course it smoothy gets through `ConvertToDoStuffInterface`, but once I try to call `DoStuff` it throws a `RuntimeBinderException` which I kinda suspected it might would. I know why the exception is thrown and it's of course because it can't properly bind the result from `ConvertToDoStuffInterface` to any type and some kind of casting is required I assume.

Here is the code for the `dynamic` usage.

```
private static dynamic ConvertToDoStuffInterface<T>(dynamic from)
{
    return (T)from;
}

public void DoStuff<T>()
{
    var i = ConvertToDoStuffInterface<T>(this);
    i.DoStuff();
}
```

My question though is if there is no better way to achieve this using either generics or `dynamic`, how would I go about doing the conversion from `dynamic` to `T`? Is there a way that I could check if the passed type to `DoStuff<T>` has a method `DoStuff` and then allow what I attempted at first?

To clarify what I want to be able to do is something like this

```
var c = new C();
c.DoStuff<A>(); // Calls A.DoStuff()
c.DoStuff<B>(); // Calls B.DoStuff()
```

Here is my `C` implementation.

```
public class C : A, B
{        
    public void DoStuff<T>()
    {
        // ... DoStuff<T> implementation here ...
    }

    void A.DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }

    void B.DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidE That's a bad practice. You should never deference an instance just after `as` keyword. It could be null. You need to have a null check there. Cleaner way is to use direct cast.

Comment: I don't understand how `c.DoStuff<A>` is cleaner than `((A)c).DoStuff`. In both cases you have to specify the interface you want to dispatch on.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing that out Sriram! (For context for future readers - I have deleted the previous comment suggesting `(A as C).DoStuff()`, which was poorly suggested)

Comment: While that is true Lee, the purpose of this is not really the readability.

Answer (score 2):

You could use these two `InvokeAs`extension methods

```
public static void InvokeAs<T>(this object obj, Action<T> action)
{
    action((T) obj);
}

public static TResult InvokeAs<T, TResult>(this object obj, Func<T, TResult> func)
{
    return func((T) obj);
}
```

And then use like this:

```
var c = new C();

c.InvokeAs<A>(x => x.DoStuff());
c.InvokeAs<B>(x => x.DoStuff());
```

But as pointed out in the comments, `((B) c).DoStuff()` is not all that bad.

Comment: This is probably the closest to what I want, but I think if this is the only way I'll go with `((B)c).DoStuff()`

Answer (score 1):

To have the behavior exactly as you want, you can use reflection:

```
class C : A, B
{
    void B.DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

    void A.DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }

    public void DoStuff<T>() 
    {
        var mi = typeof(T).GetMethod("DoStuff");
        mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { });
    }
}
```

then the call:

```
        var c = new C();
        c.DoStuff<A>();
        c.DoStuff<B>();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

works as expected.
Obviously you would have to make proper validation in the DoStuff method, if the "DoStuff" method exists and so on.

However - I don't know the use case - but it seems for me not so obvious why this is for you bether than casting.

Comment: Yup, as I said, I don't know your use case, it works, and it can be optimized, e.g. by assigning the method to a cached delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that casting is probably the cleanest (assuming you can't fix the name conflict in the interfaces), but another way would be to create two instance methods on `C` to wrap the interface calls:

```
public class C : A, B
{        
    public void DoStuff<T>()
    {
        // ... DoStuff<T> implementation here ...
    }

    void A.DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }

    void B.DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

    public void DoStuffAsA() { ((A)this).DoStuff(); }
    public void DoStuffAsB() { ((B)this).DoStuff(); }
}
```

At least it gives you compile-time safety that `dynamic`, reflection and generics don't.